# change multiple file creation date in win7

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, cmd

is there simple cmd command how to update file creation/update times under Win7.
The amount of files >100, so doing by hand is not a solution.

Ideas are welcome.

Regards,
Saulius

Answer (score 0):

Download a version of touch for Windows. http://sourceforge.net/projects/touch-win32/files/v1.21/

Different command line parameters allow you to change creation/modification/access times and you can wildcard the filenames